# Running Scripts One Time When Deployed

Tags: php, deployment, phing

We're currently using Phing for deployment and use dbdeploy to apply any database changes. However, there are occasionally changes we'd like to make during deployment that are better handled by our object model and therefore we write one time use PHP scripts that we're running manually after deployment.

Are there any existing solutions similar to dbdeploy that will handle running scripts and, more importantly, tracking which ones have run so that each script only runs once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be potentially useful for others too. If you can't think of other solution I think the best one will be to have a look at the file that implements the [DBDeploy task](http://svn.phing.info/trunk/classes/phing/tasks/ext/dbdeploy/DbDeployTask.php), copy it into a custom task, reuse the database checking functionality but instead of producing SQL scripts execute the scripts you need.

If you're happy with it you might also consider contributing it to Phing. I'm sure they will be happy to include it (see [Phing-How To Contribute](http://www.phing.info/trac/wiki/Development/HowToContribute)).

Comment: That's interesting. For some reason, I assumed most of that functionality was handled by dbdeploy itself, but it looks like a good portion of the "changelog" concept is built into the Phing task. If nothing else does exist, this would give us a great place to start a "roll your own" solution.

Comment: Yes this might be a bit confusing but the DBDeploy for PHP is actually purely the 'idea' of DBDeploy implemented in PHP as a Phing task. The script is in fact quite simple so modifying it for your needs should be quite easy. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

1. Putting your scripts in a folder.
2. Looping through the folder and execute scripts.
3. Delete/move script files once executed.

Sounds like a hack, but it's the easies way imo.

Comment: One of the advantages of the way dbdeploy operates is that it can store the changes forever and tracks which have been run. In this way, they exist in version control for all the developers to run in their development environment. For example, I can start with a fresh database, run dbdeploy and be up to date. I can do this any number of times.

Answer (score -1):

The probably easiest I can imagine would be using a **[Phing ExecTask](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixB-CoreTasks.html#ExecTask)**, see as well the [Phing User Guide (stable)](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/).

Comment: How would the ExecTask help in this case? The author of the question is asking for solution that keeps track of what scripts have run so it doesn't run then again. There's no way this can be achieved with the ExecTask. So I was just wondering...

Comment: Well as the linked manual suggest, it's just a start. Better is to create a Phing Task out of it then over time. And actually the OP asked for a script to execute once per deploy so the original question is not that precise and not how I understood it that the deploy once must be specific deploy once on (a specific system?) for the same version? on multiple systems? ...